# plugin do phonegap no AngularJS ngCordova

Tags: angularjs, apache-cordova, facebook

Eu tenho uma leve dificuldade em entender como instalar esses plugins, no geral, eles nunca funcionam por falta de algum arquivo que não chamei ou coisa parecida.

Por exemplo, esse plugin do facebook que o phonegap o força a usar para melhores resultados de performace, https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin.
Método browser via ngCordova: http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/facebook/

Eu o instalo via git-shell, tudo direitinho. Movo o arquivo js para a pasta js do meu root, chamo esse js na index, mas mesmo assim, quando vou chamar a função, ele me diz que está indefinida.

Há algo mais que eu precise saber na hora de instalar esse plugins?

Grato desde Já!

Edit:

Estou tentando inserir o método desta maneira:

```
myApp.config(function($cordovaFacebookProvider) {
var appID = 123456789;
var version = "v2.0"; // or leave blank and default is v2.0
$cordovaFacebookProvider.browserInit(appID, version);
});
```

Mas aparece o seguinte erro:  `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]`

Tentei desta maneira, mas não funcionou também:

```
$scope.testeButton = function(name,description,image){
        myApp.config(["$cordovaFacebookProvider",function($cordovaFacebookProvider) {
              var appID = xxxxxxxxxx;
              var version = "v2.5"; // or leave blank and default is v2.0
              $cordovaFacebookProvider.browserInit(appID, version);
              console.log('aqui');
            }]);

        var options = {
            method: "feed",
            link: "http://example.com",
            caption: "Such caption, very feed."
      };
        $cordovaFacebook.showDialog(options)
            .then(function(success) {
              // success
            }, function (error) {
              // error
            });
    }
```

Apareceu `cordovaFacebook is not defined`

Comment: Acho que falta injetar `angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'ngCordova', 'ui.utils.masks'])`. Assim por exemplo.

Comment: Entendi o que quis dizer, mas o que injetaria desse plugin?

Comment: Boa pergunta, lendo melhor a documentação não diz sobre injetar :(

Comment: Fico confuso nesses plugins porque a explicação é bem sucinta.

Comment: Descobri que tem que injetar um $cordovaFacebook no meu module.config, http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/facebook/.<br /> O problema agora é que adiciono isso embaixo do meu myapp, mas dá erro no app.

Comment: Tenta editar a pergunta e mostrar o erro que está dando, vai ficar melhor de entender.

Comment: parece que o modo que estou tentando instalar, não aceita.<br /> ` Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] `